# O que são as RFCs?

Tags: terminologia, http

Em perguntas relacionadas ao protocolo HTTP é muito comum ver referência a uma ou mais RFC...

- Mas o que elas são?
- Estão relacionadas apenas ao HTTP?
- Algumas são referenciadas como obsoletas, quais são as atuais?

Comment: Ótima pergunta. Eu ia pergunta a respeito do assunto em breve :)

Comment: @gato fui mais rápido :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Requests For Comments* (solicitações de comentários). É uma ideia criada pela [IETF](https://www.ietf.org/), o órgão que costuma definir como as coisas devem funcionar na internet ou redes de forma geral. Mas qualquer um pode propor RFCs. Claro pra ganhar um número oficial universal tem um [processo de conformação por editores de RFCs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2026). Existe um padrão de como uma RFC deve ser escrita, e adivinha como você descobre isso? Lendo uma...

São documentos que indicam como algo deve funcionar ou algo que tenha uma informação relevante para todos. Muitas vezes é algo como uma especificação, porém menos formal e aberto para outras pessoas participarem. Não é só assunto técnico, também fala de comportamento, de padrões que são considerados ideais quando está usando internet, tem até humor no meio, então RFC não é só sobre especificação e só sobre internet.

Alguns ganham importância tão grande que viram praticamente uma "lei informal". Em geral protocolos são definidos assim e quem faça um software que use este protocolo deveria seguir tudo o que uma RFC determina para comunicar bem com outros agentes que seguem a RFC. [HTTP é apenas um caso desses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540).

É bastante comum que uma nova RFC torne as anteriores obsoletas, Claro, em geral ela traz tudo o que ainda é relevante para o assunto ou funciona apenas como complemento dizendo em que partes de uma mais antiga não deve mais ser seguida. Como funcionam como especificação há um cuidado para não quebrar compatibilidade. RFCs são imutáveis, só uma nova substitui a antiga.

[Índice de RFCs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc-index.html). Se procurar aqui no SOpt tem diversas respostas e até perguntas que falam delas.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Conhece algum site que mostre as RFC com uma interface melhor (mais bonita, com mais recursos como filtro)?

Comment: Não, eu simplesmente procuro a que desejo e pego o txt, o Google é só o que eu uso.