# Por que em documentação a vírgula fica do lado de dentro?

Tags: documentação

Lendo documentação muitas vezes já vi isso mas não entendo porque é assim:

```
JSON.parse(text[, reviver])
```

Por que a vírgula não fica para o lado de fora? Por exemplo, assim:

```
JSON.parse(text,[ reviver])
```

Tem alguma explicação?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Os colchetes indicam que o parâmetro é opcional. A vírgula fica dentro dos colchetes porque ela própria faz parte de todo o conteúdo que é opcional.

Ou seja, se fosse assim:

```
JSON.parse(text,[ reviver])
```

Isso daria a entender que eu poderia chamar a função assim: `JSON.parse(text,)` (até pode em JS, mas em outras linguagens com sintaxe mais rígida, daria erro).

Porém, se tivéssemos, por exemplo, uma função com vários parâmetros opcionais e a vírgula fosse documentada fora dos colchetes:

```
JSON.stringify(value, [replacer], [space])
```

Aí daria a entender que eu poderia fazer `JSON.stringify(value,,)` (e isso nem o JS aceita).

---

Claro que tem um certo preciosismo e "todo mundo entenderia sem problemas" que não é para deixar essas vírgulas no final. Mas ao colocar a vírgula dentro dos colchetes, estou indicando que **todo o bloco "*vírgula + parâmetro*"** é opcional (ou coloca ambos, ou nenhum).

Sei que para alguns parece pedante, mas acho importante ter uma documentação clara, sem ambiguidades e nem margem para intepretações erradas. Sem contar que demonstra mais cuidado com os detalhes. Provavelmente é por isso que muitos colocam a vírgula dentro dos colchetes.

---

## Origem incerta

Embora a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/588596/112052) (antes de [ser editada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/588596/revisions) e apagada) tenha citado a notação [EBNF](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) (que de fato usa colchetes para indicar que algo é opcional), as origens desta notação parecem ser mais antigas.

Primeiro, vale lembrar que **não existe um padrão oficial definido para esse tipo de documentação**. Não no sentido de ter uma norma ISO, [RFC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/364753/112052), especificação, ou seja lá o que for.

Não encontrei fontes que cravam com certeza a origem exata, mas a referência mais antiga que encontrei foi o [UNIX PROGRAMMER'S MANUAL](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/1stEdman.html) (escrito em **1971**, mais de 20 anos antes do EBNF). Na [introdução](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/manintro.html) é dito que:

> *Square brackets (`[]`) around an argument indicate that the argument is optional*

Esta é portanto uma forte candidata à "origem" (pelo menos até alguém encontrar uma referência mais antiga).

Eu acho que faz sentido imaginar que este manual tenha influenciado a notação das documentações modernas. Afinal, o contexto é muito similar (documentação/manual).

E também faz sentido que essa mesma notação tenha sido usado em outros contextos, como o EBNF (que é uma notação para definir gramáticas e descrever linguagens formais, o que não tem a ver com documentação em si). Afinal, muita coisa em computação é assim, a sintaxe e terminologia de alguns contextos acabam sendo aplicados ou adaptados para outros, e o uso de colchetes para indicar algo opcional seria apenas mais um caso.

Mas creio que dá para afirmar com certo grau de certeza que a origem desta notação não é o EBNF.

---

Ver também:

- [How to interpret function parameters in software and language documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10925478)
- [Linux/Unix 'man' page syntax conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23242493)